# Probabilty of events with multiple bags filled with multiple balls.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

So there are 4 Bags filled with different colored balls. It also gives the probability of the bags to be chosen.

- Bag 1: 6 red, 7 blue, and 3 green. Bag probability .15
- Bag 2: 8 red, 8 blue, and 2 green. Bag probability .20
- Bag 3: 2 red, 9 blue, and 8 green. Bag probability .35
- Bag 4: 4 red, 7 blue, and 0 green. Bag probability .30

Calculate the probability:
A). a blue ball is chosen
D). Bag 4 was chosen if the ball is green.

There are many more questions similar to these two but if I can get help with these I should be able to figure out the others. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the probability of getting a blue ball assuming you are pulling from bag 1?  Call this $P(Blue|Bag 1)$

And, what is the probability you pulled from bag 1? $P(Bag 1) =0.15$

For any pick, the chance you pulled a blue ball from bag 1 is:

$P(Blue|Bag 1)P(Bag 1)$

The chance of pulling a blue ball then is:

$P(Blue) =  P(Blue|Bag 1)P(Bag 1) + P(Blue|Bag 2)P(Bag 2) \cdots P(Blue|Bag 4) P(Bag 4)$

d)
Given that you pulled a green ball, what is the chance it came from bag 4?

$P(Bag 4|Green) = \frac {P(Green|Bag 4) P(Bag 4)}{P(Green)}$

But, $P(Green|Bag 4) = 0$  So, you don't need to work too hard.

Comment: So would P(Blue|Bag1)P(Bag1)=7/16*.15?

Comment: You are off to a good start.

Comment: @user366839 Correct.